# Listview is not animating

Tags: java, android, listview, jazzylistview

For some reason the listview is not animating, only the textviews are. I have a feeling it has to do with the LayoutInflater but I am not sure. This is where I define the JazzyListView and its animation:

```
public class RssFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private View view;
private View view2;
private JazzyListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,container, false);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
 listView= (JazzyListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        startService();
    } else {
        
    }
    return view;
}

private void startService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RssService.class);
    intent.putExtra(RssService.RECEIVER, resultReceiver);
    getActivity().startService(intent);
}


private final ResultReceiver resultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        List<RssItem> items = (List<RssItem>) resultData.getSerializable(RssService.ITEMS);

        if (items != null) {
            RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(getActivity(), items);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The RSS feed is unable to be downloaded at this time",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listView.setTransitionEffect(JazzyHelper.GROW);
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    };
};

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
    RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff090eae"  />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="KGHS"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.JazzyListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    app:effect= "grow"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
     />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ffdedede" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="EVENTS"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="STAFF"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

As I mentioned before the textviews (the textviews are in a different xml by themselves) are animating but the actual listview  is not. I already tried changing the fragment to an activity in order to rid the view/layout inflater. Not sure what else to try.

[edit 1] Is this Android SDK animation? This is an image from the JazzyListView library sample application... I was under the impression the jazzylistview animated the listview as well, otherwise what is the point???

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Animation of `JazzyListView` animates its items but not itself. If you want to animate a `JazzyListView`, then you have to use animations provided by `Android SDK`, I am afraid.

Comment: Are you sure because they have shown animations on their sample app?

Comment: Yes I'm sure that the animation effects are not used for `ListView` itself.

Answer (score 1):

To add an animation in ListView, you first need to define an
XML containing your animation. In my case I created a fade_in.xml.
You need to put this file in res->anim->fade_in.xml folder

/res/anim/fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Then, I created a class derived from BaseAdapter so that I can override the getView
function and that is where you can insert the animation code.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_item_large_one_line, null);
  ...
   Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mainActivity, R.anim.fade_in);
   animation.setStartOffset(i*500);
   view.startAnimation(animation); 
  return view;
}
```

Comment: I did this and it didn't help the same issue